# Remove placeholder from core/image in InnerBlocks template

Tags: block-editor

I'm developing a custom gutenberg block that conditionally loads a `core/video` or a `core/image` block. I'm not usign `allowedBlocks` in `InnerBlocks` beacuse I don't want the user has to click the `+` button to insert the innerblock content. So I'm loading conditionally two `template`s, one for video and one for image.

The problem is that when the user selects the button for `core/image`, a placeholder is rendered instead of `MediaUpload`, and `MediaUpload` apperas only after the user clicks on the placeholder. I want to remove this ckick step and render immediately the `MediaUpload`.

[image: placeholder in innerblocks]

Here's my edit.js

```
export default function BFSingleImageVideoEdit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {

    const ChooseContent = () => {
      let content = ''
      if (attributes.renderedContent == "image") {
        const IMAGE_TEMPLATE = [
          [ 'core/image', {} ],
        ];
        content = <InnerBlocks template={ IMAGE_TEMPLATE } templateLock="all" />
      }
      else if (attributes.renderedContent == "video") {
        const VIDEO_TEMPLATE = [
          [ 'core/video', {} ],
        ];
        content = <InnerBlocks template={ VIDEO_TEMPLATE } templateLock="all" />
      } 
      else if (attributes.renderedContent == false) {
          content =
          <div>
              <h3>Choose an image or a video</h3>
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={ () => setAttributes({renderedContent: 'image'}) }>Image</Button>
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={ () => setAttributes({renderedContent: 'video'}) }>Video</Button>
          </div>
       }
      return content
    }

    return (
      <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
        <BlockControls></BlockControls>
        <ChooseContent />
        { attributes.renderedContent ? <Button variant="primary" onClick={ () => setAttributes({renderedContent: false}) }><>&#8592;</> back</Button> : null }
      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no easy solution. You could use `editor.BlockEdit` hook to change default core/image Edit component, and copy the code from current [trunk version](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/image/edit.js), and change there to not use `MediaPlaceholder`, but `MediaUpload` wrapped in `MediaUploadCheck`. However, that would create problem that all `core/image` blocks would be changed and it would not be futureproof, since code that you copied may change over time. You can solve the former by testing using [`getBlockParents`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-block-editor/#getblockparents) selector and if immediate parent (0 element of array) is your block that change only that instance in the filter.

However, I would create another block and use inside its edit:

```
<MediaUploadCheck>
  <MediaUpload />
</MediaUploadCheck>
```

to automatically open image uploader. This block would be instead of `core/image` in your template.